# Python function taking a lot longer than before?

Tags: python, memory

I had used gensim and Word Mover's distance to generate a distance matrix for my text of ~4000. The first time I ran it, it took about a day or so. I am trying to run it again and it is taking more than 4 days so far. Another function that runs KMedoids usually takes minutes but now takes days. I have tried using garbage collector to clear up some memory but that hasn't solved anything.

```
import gc
gc.collect()
```

I've tried restarting my computer but that also didn't help. I'm not sure what to do to fix this.

Comment: Is your RAM utilization high? Maybe you've gone into swap space/paging?

Comment: According to Activity Monitor Swap = 0 bytes

Comment: What about system resources in general? What's the bottleneck?

Comment: Python is using 1.5 GB (the highest memory used) and there is 16GB on here. Memory  = 9.10 GB, Cached Files = 6.72 GB

Comment: I mean not just RAM. Is disk usage at 100%? CPU? GPU? etc

Comment: Python is using 99% of CPU. System = 2.6%. User = 11.36%

Comment: So, you now know that the bottleneck is the CPU. As for why that started happening, now you'll have to troubleshoot. Have you tried to exactly and precisely replicate the circumstances that happened when the process took less time? Have you tried to [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-do-i-profile-a-python-script) the script to see where the "hot spots" are?